# Using regex to pull domain from URL

Tags: regex

I'm currently working on a regex query to pull out the domain name of a URL. The catch is, I only want to pull the domain if it has the following format:

[www.miami-dade.com](http://www.miami-dade.com)

If the domain is [www.miamidade.com](http://www.miamidade.com), i don't want to detect that. The part I'm struggling with is, I also don't want to detect on the domain if it has more than one dash in it. For example:

[www.florida-miami-dade.com](http://www.florida-miami-dade.com) shouldn't be detected.

This is my regex, anyone have any idea on what I should do?
(?<=.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+

Comment: Do you want to match the whole input if it has that form, or are you trying to match it from a body of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\w+\.\w+-\w+\.\w+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/mwPgQaKdyy0Aen).

The regex `\w` means "word character", which includes letters, numbers and the underscore.

If you strictly want only letters, use

```
^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$
```